# How to retrigger function (translate animation )

Tags: javascript, css

My animation function only runs once. I've tried removing and adding classes, as well as running a animationend function to create a retrigger. But still no luck. Any vanilla JS ideas?

```
CSS:
#element {
width: 10px; 
height: 10px; 
animation: "";

@keyframes movedown {
    100% {
        transform: translateY(10px);
    }
}

JS:
btn_button.onclick = () => {
    element.style.animation = "movedown 10s";
};

HTML: 
<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: That depends how many times you want your animation function to get trigger, Or you want to trigger it on an event listener. Please specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `setTimeout` to set `element.style.animation` to `""`. Then, you can add animation name again upon button click.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
btn.onclick = () => {
  element.style.animation = "movedown 2s";
  setTimeout(() => element.style.animation = "", 2000)
};
```

```css
#element {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes movedown {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
<button id="btn">Trigger</button>
```